# unable to deserialise odata to Dataset using JSON.NET due to odata.metadata

Tags: c#-4.0, json.net, odata

I'm trying to get some help on deserializing a JSON reponse to a `DataSet`.

in theory this should be easy as using this example

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDataSet.htm

```
DataSet dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(json);
DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables["Table1"];
```

However the JSON I am getting back is supplemented / decorated using "odata.metadata"

see below.

```
{"odata.metadata":"http://nodts004.cloudapp.net:7058/TNPMaster2016Dev/OData/$metadata#NP_Customer","value":[{"No":"01121212","Name":"Spotsmeyer's Furnishings","City":"Miami","Amount":"0","Customer_Posting_Group":"FOREIGN","Balance_LCY":"0","Sales_LCY":"0","Profit_LCY":"0","Balance_Due_LCY":"0","Payments_LCY":"0","Inv_Amounts_LCY":"0","Cr_Memo_Amounts_LCY":"0","Outstanding_Orders":"0","Shipped_Not_Invoiced":"0","No_of_Quotes":0,"No_of_Blanket_Orders":0,"No_of_Orders":6,"No_of_Invoices":0,"No_of_Return_Orders":0,"No_of_Credit_Memos":0,"No_of_Pstd_Shipments":0,"No_of_Pstd_Invoices":0,"No_of_Pstd_Return_Receipts":0,"No_of_Pstd_Credit_Memos":0,"No_of_Ship_to_Addresses":0,"Outstanding_Orders_LCY":"0","Shipped_Not_Invoiced_LCY":"0"},{"No":"01445544","Name":"Progressive Home Furnishings","City":"Chicago","Amount":"0","Customer_Posting_Group":"FOREIGN","Balance_LCY":"1499.02","Sales_LCY":"1499.02","Profit_LCY":"305.12","Balance_Due_LCY":"1499.02","Payments_LCY":"0","Inv_Amounts_LCY":"1499.02","Cr_Memo_Amounts_LCY":"0","Outstanding_Orders":"0","Shipped_Not_Invoiced":"0","No_of_Quotes":0,"No_of_Blanket_Orders":0,"No_of_Orders":0,"No_of_Invoices":0,"No_of_Return_Orders":0,"No_of_Credit_Memos":0,"No_of_Pstd_Shipments":1,"No_of_Pstd_Invoices":1,"No_of_Pstd_Return_Receipts":0,"No_of_Pstd_Credit_Memos":0,"No_of_Ship_to_Addresses":0,"Outstanding_Orders_LCY":"0","Shipped_Not_Invoiced_LCY":"0"},{"No":"01454545","Name":"New Concepts Furniture","City":"Atlanta","Amount":"0","Customer_Posting_Group":"FOREIGN","Balance_LCY":"222241.32","Sales_LCY":"0","Profit_LCY":"0","Balance_Due_LCY":"222241.32","Payments_LCY":"0","Inv_Amounts_LCY":"222241.32","Cr_Memo_Amounts_LCY":"0","Outstanding_Orders":"15609","Shipped_Not_Invoiced":"0","No_of_Quotes":0,"No_of_Blanket_Orders":0,"No_of_Orders":1,"No_of_Invoices":0,"No_of_Return_Orders":0,"No_of_Credit_Memos":0,"No_of_Pstd_Shipments":0,"No_of_Pstd_Invoices":0,"No_of_Pstd_Return_Receipts":0,"No_of_Pstd_Credit_Memos":0,"No_of_Ship_to_Addresses":0,"Outstanding_Orders_LCY":"8702.82","Shipped_Not_Invoiced_LCY":"0"},{"No":"01905893","Name":"Candoxy Canada Inc.","City":"Thunder Bay","Amount":"0","Customer_Posting_Group":"FOREIGN","Balance_LCY":"0","Sales_LCY":"0","Profit_LCY":"0","Balance_Due_LCY":"0","Payments_LCY":"0","Inv_Amounts_LCY":"0","Cr_Memo_Amounts_LCY":"0","Outstanding_Orders":"0","Shipped_Not_Invoiced":"0","No_of_Quotes":0,"No_of_Blanket_Orders":0,"No_of_Orders":0,"No_of_Invoices":0,"No_of_Return_Orders":0,"No_of_Credit_Memos":0,"No_of_Pstd_Shipments":0,"No_of_Pstd_Invoices":0,"No_of_Pstd_Return_Receipts":0,"No_of_Pstd_Credit_Memos":0,"No_of_Ship_to_Addresses":0,"Outstanding_Orders_LCY":"0","Shipped_Not_Invoiced_LCY":"0"},{"No":"01905899","Name":"Elkhorn Airport","City":"Elkhorn","Amount":"0","Customer_Posting_Group":"FOREIGN","Balance_LCY":"0","Sales_LCY":"0","Profit_LCY":"0","Balance_Due_LCY":"0","Payments_LCY":"0","Inv_Amounts_LCY":"0","Cr_Memo_Amounts_LCY":"0","Outstanding_Orders":"0","Shipped_Not_Invoiced":"0","No_of_Quotes":0,"No_of_Blanket_Orders":0,"No_of_Orders":0,"No_of_Invoices":0,"No_of_Return_Orders":0,"No_of_Credit_Memos":0,"No_of_Pstd_Shipments":0,"No_of_Pstd_Invoices":0,"No_of_Pstd_Return_Receipts":0,"No_of_Pstd_Credit_Memos":0,"No_of_Ship_to_Addresses":0,"Outstanding_Orders_LCY":"0","Shipped_Not_Invoiced_LCY":"0"}]}
```

I have for certain scenarios created a POCO to deal with the returned json for the properties

```
public class RootObject2
{
    [JsonProperty("odata.metadata")]
    public string odatametadata { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("odata.nextLink")]
    public string NextLinkUrl { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("odata.metadata")]
    public string odatametadata { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("odata.nextLink")]
    public string NextLinkUrl { get; set; }

    public List<UrlItem> Value { get; set; }
}
```

These are used in instances where I know the returned JSON will contain certain structures and can be safely dealt with.

The problem is that the `VALUE` part of the JSON will be dynamic in many instances and I wanted to take advantage of the dynamic nature of the `JSONConvert` functions to build `DataSet`s that I can then pass through as a source for an Excel table. It should be noted that the data coming back will never be definable.

When i use the code:

```
DataSet dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(json);
```

I get an error, because I need to be passing the sting / contents of the `VALUE` node/element to the `DeserialseObject`.

Is there a setting on the JSON converter that allows this?

I have tried to create a POCO with a `string` field and then after mapping the `VALUE` node to the POCO passing the string to the `JSONConverter` but this errors out.

A solution to this would be most helpful.

Thanks.

B....

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom subclass of [`DataSetConverter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/DataSetConverter.cs) that strips out non-array-valued properties from the root `DataSet` object:

```
public class DataSetConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.DataSetConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type valueType)
    {
        if (!base.CanConvert(valueType))
            return false;
        return typeof(DataSet).IsAssignableFrom(valueType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var token = JObject.Load(reader);
        // Strip non-array-valued properties
        foreach (var property in token.Properties().Where(p => p.Value.Type != JTokenType.Array).ToList())
            property.Remove();

        using (var subReader = token.CreateReader())
        {
            while (subReader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)
                subReader.Read();
            return base.ReadJson(subReader, objectType, existingValue, serializer); // Use base class to convert
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
var dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new JsonConverter[] { new DataSetConverter() } });
var dataTable = dataSet.Tables["value"];
```

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1boMSk).

Comment: hello, thanks for taking the time to answer my question, you help is appreciated. I need to try this out now on a couple of data sets. Thanks again.

Would you not think that JSON =.net might have this sort of thing as part of it's standard implementation for dealing with Odata returns ?